# Which Christians are right?

Tags: discussion, objectivity

It is, i hope, obvious to all that a question with this title should not be allowed on this (the main) site, as they will be devisive and argumentative. However we seem to be allowing questions that amount to the same thing.

[Communion - How frequently should it be celebrated](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/communion-how-frequently-should-it-be-celebrated) is one of those. The asker admits that they know there are different policies, but asks which one is best. The answers, predictibly, all amount to "my tradition does it this way, and I think it's the best". Voting (again predictably) seems to be based simply on how many people agree with the answer.

I hold that **this is a debate question**, since there is no possibility of a definitive answer without taking sides. It should therefore be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This site has changed a lot since I started posting here.  Once upon a time, mods used to close and edit everything.  It started to turn people off of the site.  We've since gotten more relaxed and it looks like we have a lot of activity on the site now.  Unfortunately the quality has gone down some.  I think we'll find a happy medium... someday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proposal:

Modify this question to ask for proscriptions from tradition, scripture or doctrine concerning to frequency of the celebration of communion.

This keeps the question alive in basically it's current form, but softens the debate somewhat. I've attempted an edit to make this happen.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: In general I strongly agree with this way forward. But in this case it amounts to: "Q: Different Christian traditions celebrate communion with different frequency? What are some ways different Christian traditions approach this?  A: They celebrate communion with different frequency". In other words the questioner already seems to know about different tradtions, and really wants to know what is best - an answer we can't give them.

Comment: That's very good. I didn't think it could be done, but you did it. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that my original question was not very good, as you point out, even taking into account its age. I'm sorry for that. You are quite right that it is not a good fit for the site as we now understand it, since (as written) it is asking for a normative answer about who is right.

My original intent, if I recall correctly, was to get more insight into why the traditions are different. I've had a go at rewriting the question towards that target. I am grateful to wax eagle for also attempting a rewrite, but that proposal is a bit further from what I intended to ask (and failed to ask properly), as well as being quite demanding to answer in terms of its wide scope.

Comment: It does seem as though it is taking quite a long time for the Church as a whole to get agreements on the core essentials of doctrine.  It took the first 3 centuries to figure out who Christ is.  So, figure it takes centuries to come to grips with the elemental things of the Gospel, and no wonder we're where we're at.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding:

> Voting (again predictably) seems to be based simply on how many people
>   agree with the answer.

I believe it is a common theme on this site to up vote the answer which is most aligned with one's own believe rather than up vote answers for their quality per SE guide lines.  Similarly answers are down voted for similar reasons - which is also against SE guide lines.

> **What is voting up?**
>
> Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers
>   are most useful and appropriate.
>
> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question or answer that you feel is
>   especially useful, vote it up!
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

And

> **What is voting down?**
>
> Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes", is how the community
>   indicates which questions and answers are least useful.
>
> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
>   no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is **clearly and perhaps
>   dangerously incorrect.**
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day — and answer downvotes cost
>   you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that — so use them wisely.

Highlighted is why I feel that religion SE - especially those w/o one voice are not an ideal fit for SE.  Most of all, I think there should be setting which you cannot down vote w/o commenting on why you are down voting (or upvoting a comment as I did with RiverC's answer to this question).  This does not help the author of the answer understand what is incorrect about his answer.  I do not know how to facilitate this, however.