# Would it still be a "truth question" when many different denominations arrive at the same conclusion?

Tags: discussion

Would it still be a "truth question" when many different denominations arrive at the same conclusion? Is it safe to conclude something as a "generic Christian opinion", or should I ***always*** explicitly write the denomination/religious affiliation of the writer who expresses the opinion, assuming that there may be at least one denomination somewhere in the world that disagrees?

Recently, I answered [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/is-there-a-respectful-way-to-get-rid-of-scriptures). It looks like a "truth question" to me, because it is not specifying the denomination; yet, I found out three sources (Calvary Chapel member, Fundamentalists, and Catholic) that seem to say the *same thing*. I don't know, but I think this should be one exception to the hard-and-fast rule.

On the other hand, I think I only covered Western Christianity, not Eastern. So, my answer may be biased.

Comment: That example is of a completely different genre of question and the "truth" metric doesn't really even make sense.

Comment: @Caleb So, what do you call it then? I was merely describing the question, as I thought the question looked similar to the typical "truth question" in the sense that it did not specify the denomination.

Comment: Occasionally, a question is off-topic, but the answer validates it. We have had it happen before. These really go on a case by case basis. You just have to answer before all the vtc's get in.

Comment: @fredsbend What is a vtc? I tried looking up the acronym, but that failed me.

Comment: @Anonymous vtc = Vote to close. It is an SE (Stack Exchange) specific acronym. vtr = vote to reopen.

Comment: @Anonymous it would be called tyranny of the masses.

Comment: @Anonymous I told you that in our chat! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11704/would-christianity-survive-if

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.  A Truth question is a Truth question, even if the majority agrees with it.

Put simply, [we're not here to argue who's right and who's wrong, period](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/which-christians-are-right).

That's probably the single most important guiding principle for the site.  It's what keeps us different from typical discussion forums, and what keeps os from devolving into infighting over doctrinal differences.  So if even a small minority disagrees with a view, that guiding principle applies.  We're not here to tell that minority they're wrong.

Comment: However there is nothing wrong to say that one is wrong if s/he is, though. Otherwise, if nothing is wrong everithing is right and this is, on one hand, not possible and, on the other hand, very dangerous, no?

Comment: ... and mind of a number of times when Jesus said "you are wrong", though.

Comment: ... and, wouldn't it be better to avoid *politically correctness*, at least for Christians?

Comment: D. Strat., I observed you don't have anything to say about the above comments. Well, I accept your silence, but don't forghet that Jesus said 'You don't listen to me because you aren't God's children,' though.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider I didn't address your comments here because to do so takes more words than a single commnt allows, so I addressed them with [a new Meta post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/does-this-sites-policy-against-debating-whos-right-mean-that-the-site-is-tea).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a respectful way to dispose of old or worn out scriptures?

This is **not** a "Truth" question. It is actually an **"opinion based"** question and very close to **"pastoral advice"**. Truth questions are mostly related to doctrines and believes.

Some examples of Truth seeking questions -

1. Is this doctrine right?
2. Will this denomination go to Heaven?
3. What is the right doctrine?
4. What is the right way to do this?
5. Is this a sin?

etc. etc.